# Running multiple FCGI/Django on Nginx for load sharing

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, django

I am running a web-service on Nginx/FastCGI/Django. Our processing time is fairly long and CPU intensive and I would like to be able to run multiple processes of Django/FastCGI to share the load. 
How do I set Nginx to rout requests from a single source to multiple instances of Django/FastCGI? (I can run the multiple instances on multiple ports/sockets, but I don't know how to make Nginx share the processing load between them.)

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpUpstreamModule

Works with both proxy_pass and fastcgi_pass.

Answer (score 1):

I realize the question is for fastcgi, but the easiest and speediest way to spawn and load balance a cluster of Python web applications with nginx is to NOT use fastcgi module, but to use the "uWSGI" module.
Example nginx config:

```
upstream uwsgicluster {
     server 127.0.0.1:9001;
     server 192.168.100.101:9001;
     server 192.168.100.102:9001;
     server 192.168.100.103:9001;
     server 192.168.100.104:9001;
}

server {
    listen   80;
    server_name www.mysite.com mysite.com;
    access_log /srv/www/mysite.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log /srv/www/msysite.com/logs/error.log;

    location / {
        include        uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass     uwsgicluster;
    }

    location /static {
        root   /srv/www/mysite.com/public_html/static/;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

uWSGI website is here projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/ and be sure to look at the Examples page including Django here: http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Example

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official website](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxDjangoFastCGI), you can spawn the fcgi with the parameter :

> cd {project_location}
>
> python ./manage.py runfcgi **--settings={project}.settings_production maxchildren=10** \
>
> maxspare=5 minspare=2 method=prefork socket={project_location}/log/django.sock pidfile={project_location}/log/django.pid

Or maybe in the same way as the php-fcgi works in its conf script, where I have (in `/etc/init.d/php-fcgi`) :

> PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=5